# looking for php game engine/framework

Tags: php, game-engine, mmo

I'm looking for php game engine/framework. Free or cheap, preferably open source (but it's not requirement). If there's nothing like this available I'd be fine with modifying some open source game...

I like Legend of the Green Dragon a lot (simple but enjoyable gameplay :) but it's use terms are very limited - they don't give you permissions to place ads in your game, change donations button to something else than paypal, etc...

Answer (score 5):

Googling for "php game engine"

- http://www.google.com/search?q=php+game+engine

yielded this page as 1st serp with a rather large lists of game engines.

- http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines

The only engine written in PHP according to this list is

- http://engine.nowhere-else.org/

But apparently Legend of the Green Dragon is written in PHP too and can be self hosted as well

- http://wiki.dragonprime.net/index.php?title=Requirements

Comment: Yes but lotgd's license doesn't let me to place ads on it (i think... prove me wrong). I've seen nowhere else engine and i like it but it might be a bit... too much for my needs. I don't really want all that javascript.

Comment: @Tom well, yes. It's under CC-by-nc-sa. Guess you have to look at the other linked engine then or built upon an earlier version of LOTGD, when it was still under GPL.

Comment: That's good idea! Where can I check which version was GPL??

Comment: @Tom (German) Wikipedia says CC started with 0.9.8, so I guess it 0.9.7. It's likely on the LOTGD wiki as well somewhere. Start digging.

Answer (score 3):

Game engines and frameworks don't exist for what you want. People do sell turnkey sites, where you can change the theme of a site, but it will never bring you any real progression from what they created to make a new product which would be respected.

You should grab Zend Framework, think up a game concept and develop and code it yourself from scratch.

Sites like eRepublik.com are relatively young... Check out their page and you will see how it should be done.

Comment: I'd choose Zend Framework over Symphony for a few reasons. ZF is very modular. You can use whatever you want. You are not forced to do things a certain way and can use just one class if that's all you need. ZF is backed by Zend the PHP company. There are lots of developers working with and for ZF. It's got a good future.